# F# Connect SQLProvider with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, f#, .net-core, type-providers, f#-4.0

I'm a beginner in both F# and the .Net world, I'm trying to make this F# script work:

```
#r "./packages/SQLProvider/lib/netstandard2.0/FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"
#r "./packages/SQLProvider/lib/netstandard2.0/netstandard.dll"
#r "./packages/Npgsql/lib/netstandard2.0/Npgsql.dll"

open FSharp.Data.Sql
open Npgsql

let [<Literal>] ConnString = 
    "Host=localhost;"       +
    "Port=5431;"            +
    "Database=suavetododb;" +
    "Username=postgres;"    +
    "Password=postgres"

let [<Literal>] DbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL
let [<Literal>] ResPath = @"./packages/Npgsql/lib/netstandard2.0"

type Sql =
    SqlDataProvider<
        DbVendor,
        ConnString,
        "",
        ResPath,
        1000,
        true>
```

This is the error I get:

> error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: Could not resolve field token 0x04000523, due to: Could not load type of field 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection+d__28:<>u__2' (7) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. assembly:System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 type: member:(null) signature: assembly:(my_filesystem)/API/packages/Npgsql/lib/netstandard2.0/Npgsql.dll type:d__28 member:(null) signature:

Which is weird, since `Npgsql` is actually imported (so the last `#r` actually works).

The database is up via docker:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4704763ec2ba        suave_rezoom_db:0.1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 hours ago        Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:5431->5432/tcp   todo_rezoom_1
```

Also, the project was generated via the .Net Core 2.1.200 and is running on Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the type provider needs to resolve dependencies of the third-party driver (`Npgsql` in this case), and it can't because it doesn't have access to the full dependency tree like NuGet (or Paket) does.  You need to copy `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` to the same folder where `Npgsql.dll` sits (your `ResPath`) so that the type provider can resolve that assembly.

Once you do that, you'll find that you also need to copy `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`.